# Django 2.0: Url path to homepage/index

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to set my django homepage, linked to the root of my website: i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/` but instead, I keep getting errors where Django is searching for myapp as the homepage: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/`. I would just like to land on a homepage with "index" in the url instead of "myapp/"

**The error is as follows:**

```
Using the URLconf defined in Main.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
[name='myapp_index']
publications/ [name='publications']
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, myapp/, didn't match any of these.
```

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**Main/urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**myapp/urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from logbook import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.myapp_index, name='myapp_index'),
    path('publications/', views.publications, name='publications'),
]
```

Now, if I change the path in **Main/urls.py** to `path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),` I land on the appropriate homepage, except, I would prefer that there is "index/" listed in the URL instead of "myapp/".

I may be missing something very simple here. This is what I think is my MWE, happy to add more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I was cracking my head finding a solution.

**The solution was to erase browser's cache and history**
I realized that because when I tried with incognito mode worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This should be in the main urls.py

```
path('', views.index, name='index')
```

instead of my_app/urls.py

Answer (score 0):

```
path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls'))
path('index/', include('myapp.urls'))
```

That might get the desired result.

Comment: It doesn't work unless I have this is in the myapp/urls file: path('myapp/', views.index, name='index'),

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following:

**Main/urls**

```
 ...
 path(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
 ...
```

**myapp/urls**

```
 ...
 path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
 # path('', views.myapp_index, name='myapp_index'), ## REMOVE THIS ROW ##
 ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Those are deprecated methods as per Django.

Comment: How do you access this page - do you click on some link or just type url in address bar? If it is link - did you checked if href accidently contains 'myapp' in url?

Comment: Also, do you successful access 'publications/' addresses?

Comment: Its actually the homepage when I start the development server on pycharm. http://127.0.0.1:8000/. The publications/ link works fine, and the link goes to publications/ in the address bar. I just need the homepage to have "index/" in it but it keeps searching for myapp/ (or in real life, it is "logbook/" that it is looking for. I was using "myapp/" for generic usage.)

Comment: In your myapp.urls you have two rows pointing to ' ' url. Do you really have both index and myapp_index actions in myapp.views? You should have only one url definition pointing to ' '. So, please, try here to write '^$' (to highlight an empty url), and choose only one definiyion (index or myspp_index, what actually works). Also, in main urls instead of ' ' write '^' to highlight empty prefix.

Comment: I get a warning when I add the caret to the empty url (I am using Django 2): 
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' [name='logbook_index'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().

Comment: Views.py you ptovided in post is hlobsl views.py or inside of myapp dir? Did you remove second row pointing to ' ' url?

Answer (score 0):

first you must choose one of below lines in myapp.urls and delete other

you can not set two views for one url patterns

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('', views.myapp_index, name='myapp_index'),
```

you have two solution for get index/ as main url

1.change Main.urls like below

```
path('', include('myapp.urls')),
```

to

```
path('index/', include('myapp.urls')),
```

2.change myapp.urls like below

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

to

```
path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
```

you actually changed name of urls that using in python codes not path of urls

**edit**
Do you mean index/ like the following?

www.example.com/

so u must do that as above but delete "index/"

so u cant do it as below :

change Main.urls like below

```
path('', include('myapp.urls')),
```

to

```
path('^$', include('myapp.urls')),
```

or

change myapp.urls like below

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

to

```
path('^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: Django is still constantly looking for: "myapp/", even when I am sure I have zero reference to it. I get the error:  "The current path, myapp/, didn't match any of these."

Comment: are u mean as index is be as below?
www.example.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (Django2) - pointing to index action in 'static_pages' app's views.py as home page:

main urls.py:

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path, include

 urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('', include('static_pages.urls')), #included urls from static_pages app
 ]
```

static_pages/urls.py:

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.index, name="index"),
 ]
```

static_pages/views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse

 def index(request):
     return HttpResponse("First Django2 Message!")
```

Note that 'static_pages' app is added to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Now, calling http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I got: "First Django2 Message!".

Comment: I hear you, and it makes sense. That is what is in the Django tutorials. In my settings.py file, I have "'logbook'," in there, or for this example "'myapp',". The error remains the same" looking for "myapp/", or "logbook/" in my home example. Something is causing django to look for "myapp/" and I cant figure out what file might be driving it.

Comment: Somewhere that must be typed and it should be in some urls.py file. In final, if you are on Unix, you can grep for 'myapp' string and review all the matches